# GCDAsyncSocket authentication client self signed certificate

Tags: java, android, ios, gcdasyncsocket

I am developing an SSL socket server using the **GCDAsyncSocket**.

I would like to know if is possible validate the client certificate or an equivalent function like `setNeedClientAuth` in Java?